# How would I use my backup for my 1inch wallet to get back into my wallet

Tags: backup, wallet

Need to get back into my wallet with my backup

I don't know how to do it I've tried to get into my wallet to hard for me to do it on my own need help please tell me what to do answer this question for me I must get into my wallet